# Netbeans stuck when installing

Tags: java, installation, netbeans

I'm using latest windows 10, Java JDK 15.0.2 and I wang to install Netbeans 12.2.
When I choose "Accept lisense" and click next, an error report occurs and then it uses 0% CPU.
I have installed Netbeans and uninstalled it.
I have changed my JDK and Netbeans version, it still doesn't work.
This is the error information.
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26uKz.png)
Don't care about the time information:)

Comment: At a guess it looks like the installer is corrupted, or there are issues saving/writing the installation files. Try to download and run the installer again, or if that doesn't work try to run it as an administrator user to make sure there are no issues with writing files.

Comment: I did as this but it still did't work. Anyhow thank you